# Как правильно подключить библиотеку Fontawesome через NPM?

Tags: html, npm, scss, fontawesome

Установлено `npm update @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`.В `node__modules` есть папка `@fortawesome`.Подключаю к `style.scss` так -
`@import "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.min.css";`. Использую в HTML "fab fa-brands fa-facebook-f", иконки не отображаются.
`<i class="fab fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>`
Как правильно подключить библиотеку fontawesome через npm? Через импорт не получается.